# Running GDAL from the command line on Windows 10 x64

Tags: python, d3.js, gis, gdal

I need help getting gdal set up on my 64-bit Windows 10 machine. I am able to run `gdalinfo`, but nothing that depends on the python libraries (like `gdal_polygonize` for example).

### Expected results

I want to be able to successfully run something like `gdal_polygonize myFile.png -f "GeoJSON" myOutputFile.geojson`

### What I've tried

I used this installer: `gdal-300-1900-x64-core.msi`

With these python libraries: `GDAL-3.0.4.win-amd64-py3.7.msi` (I am using python 3.7)

I added `C:\Program Files\GDAL` to the end of  my PATH, and added the following environment variables:

[image]

For some reason, I can't run anything but `gdalinfo`. Any ideas on where to look or what I might have done wrong? This is the output in git bash, and it is the same in cmd. 
[image]

Comment: did you try `gdal_polygonize.py`?

Comment: @Val Running that now, I get the following output: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files/GDAL/gdal_polygonize.py", line 36, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'

This points to Ian Turton's answer, working on that now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the python bindings for GDAL.

The easiest way is to use the Osgeo4w installer and make sure to check the gdal-python box in the installer.

You need to use the advanced install option and expand the libs item to find gdal-python.

[image]

You then pick the same version number as the version of GDAL you are installing.

Comment: I ran the 64-bit installer listed [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) but foolishly ran the express install. Had no options for gdal-python. Uninstalled, trying to reinstall now but the UI for advanced setup is convoluted. There is an icon next to each category with up/down arrows in a circle with text that cycles between default, install, reinstall, and uninstall, but none of those seem appropriate. Each individual library has the same icon cycling between skip and some version numbers. Do I have the wrong installer? Is there an alternative, maybe less bloated way to get the bindings?

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved your problem to help others